# C# call generic interface method from non generic parent interface without dynamic

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic

Say we have a non generic base interface, with a generic inheriting interface:

```
public interface IFoo { }
public interface IBar<T, K> : IFoo { 
    K Do(T t);
}

public class BarImpl : IBar<Type, AnotherType> {
    public AnotherType Do(Type type) {
        return new AnotherType(type);
    }
}
```

I need to create a factory which returns an IFoo instance, but using the returned instance I need to be able to call the derived types Do(T), which isn't available.

```
public class FooFactory() {
    IFoo Get() {
           // simplified, in reality i am returning the correct
           // type by checking the generic interface
           // types to get an object from a stored list 
           // of implementations
           return BarImpl();
    }
}

// Now in another class
public void DoFoo() {
    IFoo iFoo = new FooFactory().Get();
    // Need to be able to call iFoo.Do(Type) but cannot
}
```

The only way I have been able to get this to work is to create a dynamic object, instead of IFoo, and then call Do() - which does work in my case but I lose some type safety which i'd prefer to keep.

My question is can I re-engineer this to be able to get access to the derived interfaces method, whilst still being able to maintain a list (and subsequently factory method return type) of IFoo????

Comment: Either cast your `IFoo Get()` to `BarImpl` or overthink your design. Nothing more to say unless you get more concrete

Comment: Your type is `IFoo`; there is no type-safety that you could call `Do` (which is part of `IBar<T, K>`). How do you expect this to work?!

Comment: using C# 6.0: `(iFoo as IBar<type1, type2>).Do(typeof(type1));`

Comment: To keep type safety? I don't see any type safety in this design. The factory is returning `IFoo`, so there is no any guarantee that the returned type implements `IBar<,>`, and even if it does, what are the type arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You expect or want type safety, but think about it this way:

- In order to be able to call `Do`, `Get` needs to return a type which defines that method. `IFoo` does not have it, but `IBar<T, K>` does. `Get` however returns an `IFoo` object which is not guaranteed to be a `IBar<T, K>`.
- Even if the implementation of `Get` would make sure that only a `IBar<T, K>` is returned, there is no way the type system would know this *without actually returning that type*.
- Assuming you could return a type that allowed you to call the `Do` method, the type would be unclear: You need to pass it an object of type `T`. But the returned `IFoo` or `IBar<T, K>` does not necessarily use the same type `T` that you wanted to pass to `Do`.
- Even if the implementation of `Get` would provide this (like “Get me an `IBar<T, K>` that accepts the type `T`”) and the type system would have a way to reflect this, then this still wouldn’t say anything about `K`. For a known `T`, it could still be an `IBar<T, int>`, or an `IBar<T, string>`. And there is actually no way to know that without actually having the concrete type.
- And still, assuming that this would work with the type system: What purpose would this actually serve? You could call the method of your generic type with your correct typed argument: But the return value still has no concrete type. You couldn’t say anything about the returned type from `Do`.

My point is that you only need generic types, when you actually have a reason to maintain a concrete type. Usually if you call a generic method or a method of a generic type from another non-generic method, then you either have a discrete set of types you’re working with, or you don’t actually need the generic type information.

So maybe you’re better off introducing a non-generic `IBar` type here:

```
interface IBar
{
    object Do(object t);
}
interface IBar<T, K> : IBar
{
    K Do(T t);
}

public class BarImpl : IBar<Type, AnotherType>
{
    public AnotherType Do(Type type)
    {
        return new AnotherType(type);
    }

    public object Do(object t)
    {
        return Do((Type) t);
    }
}
```

Then you could make `Get` return an `IBar` instead, and you have a way to call `Do`.

Btw. this pattern is used pretty commonly in the BCL, e.g. [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) and [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it will work, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `object DoIt()` method to `IFoo`, then `BarImpl` would implement it:

```
public object DoIt()
{
    return Do(typeof(T));
}
```

The problem here is that you would then need to cast the return of `DoIt` to the actual type. But you won't know apriori what that is.

Comment: I believe the `Type` type in OP’s code was just an example and not meant to be literally `System.Type`.